# fb feed_share generate a blank page on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, fb.ui

Hi Guys i have a problem
Here the code

```js
function fb_share(url, destination) {
  FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      link: url,
    },
    function(response) {
      if (response && !response.error_code) {
        url = destination;
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json"
        }).done(function(response) {
          if (response.status == 'ko') {
            showMessageModal(response.title, response.message);
          } else {
            showMessageModal(response.title, response.message, response.goto, response.removeDOM, response.addDOM);
          }
        });
        showMessageModal(response.title, response.message, response.goto, response.removeDOM, response.addDOM);
      }
    });
} {
  scope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends'
};
```

when I share a post from my site using a smartphone appears to me a blank page
https://m.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/feed
Why? I have done something wrong in the code?
Tnks all